# Persistance error when extending Tabs component from Core Components (AEM)

Tags: aem, sightly

Im using core components version 2.7.
Im trying to extend/proxy the Tabs component under core Components - `/apps/core/wcm/components/tabs/v1/tabs`

For this I created my component and as per the documentation I copied editConfig.xml to the component node.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:isContainer="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:description="Core Tab component"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Core Tabs"
    sling:resourceSuperType="/apps/core/wcm/components/tabs/v1/tabs"
    componentGroup="My Components"/>
```

This is the editConfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afterchilddelete="CQ.CoreComponents.panelcontainer.v1.AFTER_CHILD_DELETE"
        afterchildinsert="CQ.CoreComponents.panelcontainer.v1.AFTER_CHILD_INSERT"
        afterchildmove="CQ.CoreComponents.panelcontainer.v1.AFTER_CHILD_MOVE"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Now when I try to edit this component and save the changes in the dialog, I get the following error -

```
    /Test/_jcr_content/root/coretabs HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing.
org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Unable to commit changes to session.
        at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:519) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.18]
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.providers.stateful.AuthenticatedResourceProvider.commit(AuthenticatedResourceProvider.java:215) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.8]
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.helper.ResourceResolverControl.commit(ResourceResolverControl.java:422) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.8]
        at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.commit(ResourceResolverImpl.java:989) [org.apache.sling.resourceresolver:1.6.8]
        at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractPostOperation.run(AbstractPostOperation.java:164) [org.apache.sling.servlets.post:2.3.26]
        at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:228) [org.apache.sling.servlets.post:2.3.26]
        at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:146) [org.apache.sling.api:2.18.4]
        at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:342) [org.apache.sling.api:2.18.4]
        at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:374) [org.apache.sling.api:2.18.4]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:552) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:44) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:192) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:159) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:375) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:190) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.page.PageLockFilter.doFilter(PageLockFilter.java:91) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:94) [com.day.cq.cq-personalization:5.12.36]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:82) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.assetlinkshare.AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.doFilter(AdhocAssetShareAuthHandler.java:437) [com.day.cq.dam.cq-dam-core:5.12.170]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:109) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.cq.social.ugcbase.security.impl.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:126) [com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-ugcbase-impl:2.5.2]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.dam.core.impl.servlet.ActivityRecordHandler.doFilter(ActivityRecordHandler.java:141) [com.day.cq.dam.cq-dam-core:5.12.170]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.rest.impl.servlet.ApiResourceFilter.doFilter(ApiResourceFilter.java:70) [com.adobe.granite.rest.api:1.1.16]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:134) [com.adobe.granite.requests.logging:1.0.20]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.rest.assets.impl.AssetContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(AssetContentDispositionFilter.java:96) [com.adobe.granite.rest.assets:1.0.58]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at au.com.XXXXXX.retail.aem.commons.components.filters.TidyFilter.doFilter(TidyFilter.java:135) [au.com.XXXXXX.retail.aem.commons:19.1.0.rc_4-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.XXXXXX.oshc.aem.filters.TidyFilter.doFilter(TidyFilter.java:84) [com.XXXXXX.oshc:13.3.0.rc_14-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.XXXXXX.digital.aem.retail.filters.CorporateFilter.doFilter(CorporateFilter.java:75) [com.XXXXXX.digital.aem-retail:20.0.0.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:372) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:248) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-mobile-core:5.11.10]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:107) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91) [com.adobe.cq.social.cq-social-commons:1.10.74]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-foundation:5.12.20]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:138) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-foundation:5.12.20]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:76) [com.adobe.granite.optout:1.0.0]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FormsHandlingServletHelper.handleFilter(FormsHandlingServletHelper.java:226) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-foundation:5.12.20]
        at com.adobe.cq.wcm.core.components.internal.servlets.CoreFormHandlingServlet.doFilter(CoreFormHandlingServlet.java:126) [com.adobe.cq.core.wcm.components.core:2.7.0]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90) [com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-core:5.12.96]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:122) [com.adobe.cq.cq-history:5.10.6]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.cq.mcm.campaign.servlets.CampaignCopyTracker.doFilter(CampaignCopyTracker.java:100) [com.day.cq.mcm.cq-mcm-campaign:1.3.12]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:87) [org.apache.sling.rewriter:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:81) [com.adobe.granite.httpcache.core:1.0.8]
        at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:60) [com.adobe.granite.httpcache.core:1.0.8]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.csrf.impl.CSRFFilter.doFilter(CSRFFilter.java:217) [com.adobe.granite.csrf:1.0.20.CQ650-B0002]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ContentDispositionFilter.doFilter(ContentDispositionFilter.java:152) [org.apache.sling.security:1.1.16]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:78) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:83) [com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper:1.0.4]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:244) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:123) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:86) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:308) [com.adobe.granite.license:1.2.10]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:131) [org.apache.sling.i18n:2.5.14]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:116) [org.apache.sling.featureflags:1.2.2]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:72) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.parameters.RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.doFilter(RequestParameterSupportConfigurer.java:63) [org.apache.sling.engine:2.6.18]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:142) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationChain.doFilter(InvocationChain.java:81) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher$1.doFilter(Dispatcher.java:146) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1002) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:326) [org.apache.sling.security:1.1.16]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:97) [org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter:1.2.6]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.PreprocessorHandler.handle(PreprocessorHandler.java:136) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager$2.doFilter(WhiteboardManager.java:1008) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.whiteboard.WhiteboardManager.invokePreprocessors(WhiteboardManager.java:1012) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:91) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:49) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) [org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api:1.1.2]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:873) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:542) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1701) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1668) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683) [org.apache.felix.http.jetty:4.0.8]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.jcr.InvalidItemStateException: OakState0001: Unresolved conflicts in /content/retail/en/Test/jcr:content
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:238) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-api:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException.asRepositoryException(CommitFailedException.java:213) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-api:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.newRepositoryException(SessionDelegate.java:669) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:495) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl$8.performVoid(SessionImpl.java:420) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.performVoid(SessionDelegate.java:273) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:417) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        at com.adobe.granite.repository.impl.CRX3SessionImpl.save(CRX3SessionImpl.java:208) [com.adobe.granite.repository:1.6.28]
        at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.commit(JcrResourceProvider.java:517) [org.apache.sling.jcr.resource:3.0.18]
        ... 143 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.api.CommitFailedException: OakState0001: Unresolved conflicts in /content/retail/en/Test/jcr:content
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.commit.ConflictValidator.failOnMergeConflict(ConflictValidator.java:115) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-core:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.commit.ConflictValidator.propertyAdded(ConflictValidator.java:84) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-core:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeEditor.propertyAdded(CompositeEditor.java:82) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.propertyAdded(EditorDiff.java:81) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareProperties(SegmentNodeState.java:660) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:523) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:147) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:598) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:147) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:422) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:651) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:147) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:422) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:651) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:147) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:422) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:651) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.childNodeChanged(EditorDiff.java:147) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.MapRecord.compare(MapRecord.java:422) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeState.compareAgainstBaseState(SegmentNodeState.java:651) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorDiff.process(EditorDiff.java:51) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.EditorHook.processCommit(EditorHook.java:54) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeHook.processCommit(CompositeHook.java:60) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.commit.CompositeHook.processCommit(CompositeHook.java:60) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-store-spi:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.scheduler.Commit.apply(Commit.java:105) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.scheduler.LockBasedScheduler.execute(LockBasedScheduler.java:308) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.scheduler.LockBasedScheduler.schedule(LockBasedScheduler.java:279) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.SegmentNodeStore.merge(SegmentNodeStore.java:211) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-segment-tar:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableRoot.commit(MutableRoot.java:250) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-core:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.commit(SessionDelegate.java:346) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.save(SessionDelegate.java:493) [org.apache.jackrabbit.oak-jcr:1.10.2]
        ... 148 common frames omitted
```

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error. Please note that if I use the `tabs` component under core directly on the page it works well. But the proxy component doesn't.

please help

Comment: `OakState0001: Unresolved conflicts in /content/retail/en/Test/jcr:content` seems to be saying there are some properties there that cannot be merged with the changes from the saved component. Can you show us the current properties and values of `/content/retail/en/Test/jcr:content` and the dialog for your extended component?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the log extracts you posted are truncated, `POST`-ing to `/Test/_jcr_content/root/coretabs` looks weird, should be `/content/retail/en/Test/_jcr_content/root/coretabs` instead. This, and some bad alias/rewrite might explain why you have conflicts on `/content/retail/en/Test/jcr:content`.

You should be able to track the actual requests in your browser developer tools and see what happens when you try to save the changes. You can compare that with the Core Components [examples](https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/tree/master/examples/ui.apps/src/content/jcr_root/apps/core-components-examples/components/tabs) which you can [install locally](http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/core-components-examples/library/container/tabs.html) that also uses a proxy for the Tabs component.